# append javascript to head - firefox ok, but fails on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, dom

I use following function to include javascript file to head, it works on firefox but on chrome got error in little bug called "Access to restricted URI denied."

File seems to be loaded into DOM but i cant use functions from that file.

`function load(src){
    $('script[src="' + src + '"]').remove();
    $('<script>').attr('src', src+"?"+Math.random()).appendTo('head');
}`

`load('/my/local/file.js');`

Do anyone got an idea how to fix it?

Thanks for any reply.

Comment: FYI, it does you no good to remove an existing `<script>` tag.  That doesn't cause anything to change in the javascript environment.  Once the script has been parsed, removing the script tag doesn't undo anything.

Comment: Does the script load if you directly place it in the html code? Probably a setting in the browser, or an extension in chrome blocks loading the script with that error.

Comment: Thanks for reply jfriend00 and t.niese, that was good tips, well sloved, file contains some syntax errors, so chrome got more restricted rules than firefox..

Answer (score 0):

Try it with pure js to be compatible with all browsers:

```
var myHead = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('src', 'myJsFileSource');

myHead.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, i just realized why it was error - because of Math.rand() but it doesnt slove problem function from script doesnt load on chrome

Answer (score 0):

Removed the `/` from `script` source and try as below:

Replace `load('/my/local/file.js');` with `load('my/local/file.js');`